# Как менять родительский блок

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как с помошью Vue JS заменить тег родительского блока? Например li.parent на span.parent

Пример по ссылке https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/339447/

```
<ul>
<li v-for="todo in todos" class="parent">
  <span class="child">{{ todo.text }}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Или я не понял, что вы хотите или просто добавьте tag `<li v-for="todo in todos" class="parent child" tag="span" v-text="todo.text">` и получится в ul список из span

Comment: и чем это решит задачу? Думаю, что вы не поняли. Нужно заменить li на span Теги взяты для примера.

Comment: @someUser, нужно брать другой пример, потому что в `ul` могут быть только `li`, и даже если ты поменяешь `li` на `span` - то результаты могут удивить

Comment: [Динамическое переключение компонентов](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 0):

Использовал [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) чтобы получить элемент.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/341044/)

```
const myElement = this.$refs.myElement // получает элемент по ref
const tag = this.$refs.myElement.tagName.toLowerCase()  // tag элемента
const re = new RegExp(tag, 'g') // RegExp для замены
const newTag = 'span' // новый тег

// замена outerHTML на новый
myElement.outerHTML = myElement.outerHTML.replace(re, newTag)
```

Answer (score 0):

В справке описана возможность [динамического переключения компонентов](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Для этого нужно воспользоваться элементом `<component>` и директивой `is`.

В директиву передается *название* нужного компонента либо объект с настройками.

Например:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [{
        text: "Learn JavaScript"
      },
      {
        text: "Learn Vue"
      },
      {
        text: "Play around in JSFiddle"
      },
      {
        text: "Build something awesome"
      }
    ],
    cmp: 'li'
  },
  methods: {}
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ul>
    <component v-bind:is="cmp" v-for="todo in todos" class="parent">
      <span class="child">{{ todo.text }}</span>
    </component>
  </ul>
  <input type="button" value="change" @click="cmp = 'span'" />
</div>
```